# why is $http.get not working

Tags: angularjs, json

Im having a problem trying to access a json file. I used alert to determine whether it was working but for some reason it isn't. I was wondering if any of you knew why, thanks

```
app.controller("MainController", function($scope, $http) {

$http.get('/Users/singh/Documents/twilioproject/Public/patients.json').success(function(data) {
    alert('worked');
    $scope.patients = data;

  });

});
```

Comment: In what way is it "not working"? Are you getting a specific error message?

Comment: the alert('worked'); is not executing, which is what i am using to see if scope.patients = data; is working

Comment: @Nik Check your path is right!

Comment: ive changed it to the exact path but it still isn't working

Comment: Maybe add an error callback and log out the error to see if something is failing.

Comment: @Nik Any errors in the network console?

Comment: @try to add error method in the chain, it will help you to check if there is any error. And also check if you have any error in console

Comment: I also wanted to say Im using chrome, and I know for some people it doesnt work using that particular browser, which may or may not be the issue

Comment: Cannot GET /Users/singh/Documents/twilioproject/Public/patients.json is the error im having according to the error callback

Comment: @Nik just to confirm any error in browser console?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/Users/singh/Documents/twilioproject/Public/patients.json 404 (Not Found) is what the browser console says

Comment: Ok, Then you are doing it in wrong way. you are trying to access a resource which is outside your server directory, which is not allowed. Means you can not access a folder outside your server directory.

Comment: Check the network tab in Chrome to see if it the http succeeds or not.

Comment: if I use the relative path i get undefined and for the console error I get SyntaxError: Unexpected token : in JSON at position 11

Comment: The file will need to go in the same directory as your web application. You can't bust out into the users folder for very good security reasons.

Comment: and to clarify Im using  OS

Comment: for that paste your json too or check yourself if the json is correct or not

Comment: What version of Angularjs are you using?

Comment: made a dumb mistake, posted the solution

Answer (score 2):

I made a dumb mistake. My syntax for my json file was incorrect. Sorry I'm still a beginner trying to get a hang of things. Thanks for everyone for helping me out.

This is how it originally was:

```
"Patient":[
    {
        "name": "John Smith",
        "date": "12/22/2016",
        "number": "+10813924630"

    },
    {
        "name": "Johsddn Smith",
        "date": "12/22/2016",
        "number": "+14813924640"

    }
    ]
```

After I changed it to this it worked:

```
[
  {
    "name": "John Smith",
    "date": "12/22/2016",
    "number": "+15812914640"

  },
  {
    "name": "Johsddn Smith",
    "date": "12/22/2016",
    "number": "+17813923440"

  }
]
```

Comment: we don't make mistakes, just **happy little accidents** :)

Comment: thats very true haha